# Can keepass require a password when computer is locked?

Tags: windows-10, keepass

Is there a way to make it so keepass needs the master password again when you lock the computer or put it to sleep? The point is I don't trust Window's crappy password protection enough.

Comment: [This should already happen](http://keepass.info/help/base/faq_tech.html#noautolock)

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the settings on Tools > Options > Security tab:

[image]